# Enviar una variable PHP a una ventana modal para procesarlo en él

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto el cual es generar automáticamente códigos QR según un ID.

Con este código puedo mandar el ID y luego procesarlo, pero en una pagina diferente:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="../ajax/poderes/qr/qr.php?idpo=<?php echo $row['idpo']; ?>&codigo=<?php echo $row['codigo']; ?>">
<i class="fa fa-qrcode" style="color: #5cb85c; font-size:15px;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Codigo Qr"></i><span style="color: black; font-size:12px;"> CODIGO QR</span>
</a>
```

Ahora estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo, pero en vez de que se vaya a otra página quisiera que se muestre en una ventana modal.

Pero ahí es donde surgen los problemas y no puedo capturar mi ID en la ventana modal y luego procesarlo con PHP.

En este código trato de enviar el id al modal:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="../../html/modal_poderes/modal_qr.php?id=<?php echo $row['idpo']; ?>" data-target="#qrModal" class="qr" data-toggle="modal" id='.$row["idpo"].'>
    <i class="fa fa-qrcode" style="color: black; font-size:15px;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="qr"></i><span style="color: #0275d8; font-size:12px;"> QR</span>
</a>
```

Y en la ventana modal trato de capturarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$id = intval($_GET['idpo']);
echo $id;
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna manera de poder hacerlo? solo necesito que me llegue el ID para procesarlo con PHP en la ventana modal.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?]. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Con el código proporcionado no es posible reproducir tu problema, ya que tal y como lo haces yo consigo recibir la variable GET sin problemas si uso un enlace normal (continua).

Comment: Pero creo que el problema es posible que radique en que, si estás usando bootstrap para la ventana modal, pienses que se procesa el enlace proporcionado en `href` cuando pulsas en él, cuando eso no es así. Aparece la ventana modal, pero ésta contiene lo que hayas definido en el HTML, no más. Quizá quieras usar el paso de parámetros para algo, pero habría que ver el uso que quieres darle.

Answer (score 0):

Quizá estás presuponiendo incorrectamente que una ventana modal va a cargar la URL que le proporcionas en `href`.

En su lugar debes proporcionar la URL en un campo que pueda ser leído cuando se genere el evento de mostrar la ventana modal.

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo hacer esto:

```js
/* Cuando se vaya a mostrar la ventana modal obtendo la imagen para cambiarla */
$('#qrModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (evento) {
  /* Obtengo la imagen de "data-imagen" */
  const imagen = $(evento.relatedTarget).data("imagen");
  /* Busco la imagen para cambiar su "src" */
  $(this).find('.modal-body img').prop("src", imagen);
  /* Para depurar, también muestro la URL */
  $(this).find('.modal-body span').text(imagen);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<a
  class="dropdown-item"
  data-imagen="../../html/modal_poderes/modal_qr.php?id=1"
  data-target="#qrModal"
  class="qr"
  data-toggle="modal"
  id='.$row["idpo"].'
>
  <i class="fa fa-qrcode"
    style="color: black; font-size: 15px;"
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    title="qr"
  ></i><span style="color: #0275d8; font-size:12px;"> QR 1</span>
</a>


<a
  class="dropdown-item"
  data-imagen="../../html/modal_poderes/modal_qr.php?id=2"
  data-target="#qrModal"
  class="qr"
  data-toggle="modal"
  id='.$row["idpo"].'
>
  <i class="fa fa-qrcode"
    style="color: black; font-size: 15px;"
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    title="qr"
  ></i><span style="color: #0275d8; font-size:12px;"> QR 2</span>
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="qrModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Código QR</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="" />
        URL a usar:<span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```